# The relationship with $(\mathbf{u}^TA\mathbf{v})$ and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra problem comes from analysis. But I'm not familar with linear algebra now. Let $\mathbf{u},~\mathbf{v}$ be two $n\times 1$ column vectors. $A$ be a symmetric matrix. Then does $(\mathbf{u}^TA\mathbf{v})^T$ equals to $(\mathbf{u}^TA\mathbf{v})$?

Comment: The matrix ${\bf u}^T A {\bf v}$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix. So it is the same as its transpose.

Comment: I see, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u^tAv$ is a scalar, so it is same as it's transpose, for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$. $A$ need not even be symmetric.

Comment: I see... It's a silly question ha. :P